# Django Paypal subscriptions

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

Thanks to anyone who can help me answer this. I'm running a Django e-learning service that requires a one-time payment subscription that lasts 90 days. I have used [django-paypal](https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal) to integrate my payment. I use IPN (Instant Payment Notification) on Website Payments Standard as my main mode of payment.

The question -- on receiving the IPN signal `payment_was_successful`, I signal the following permission:

```
def purchase_success(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    student = User.objects.get(username=str(ipn_obj.custom))
    permission = Permission.objects.get(name="Subscribed")
    student.user_permissions.add(permission)
payment_was_successful.connect(purchase_success)
```

I am trying to figure out how to "expire" the subscription in 90 days automatically. i.e.:

```
permission - Permission.objects.get(name="Subscribed")
student.user_permissions.remove(permission)
```

Comment: Add a `subscription_date` to the relevant model, and check against that? That also gives you the ability to a) monitor subscription rates and patterns, and; b) add another column later to track `subscription_type` or `subscription_duration` if you want to offer differing lengths later.

Comment: yeah thanks. i was thinking of doing that. But I would have to call the function that checks dates for me right? Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: You are not going to run in within the django project. This task should run each day on all of your users to figure if the subscription ends.

Comment: Thanks I guess I could try that. How do i get it to run automatically every day? Suppose the user doesn't login or use the system.

Comment: Celery is built for this: http://celery.github.com/celery/getting-started/introduction.html Run a background task every hour/hours/day, and change the users' status to unsubscribed. Redirect them to a resub page if it expires and they attempt to log in ;)

Answer (score 0):

No tested but from what I know, it might work.

Paypal can handle subscriptions for you:
https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal/blob/master/README.md#using-paypal-payments-standard-with-subscriptions

```
"p3": 90,                          # duration of each unit (depends on unit)
"t3": "D",                         # duration unit ("D for Day")
```

Your signal will probably not be payment_was_successful but be one of these:

```
subscription_cancel - Sent when a subscription is cancelled.
subscription_eot - Sent when a subscription expires.
subscription_modify - Sent when a subscription is modified.
subscription_signup - Sent when a subscription is created.
```

Good luck, I've found django-paypal quite confusing!